# Create foreign keys from Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

How to automatically create foreign keys from Rails associations? The best solution should generate Rails database migration from Rails associations.

Comment: not clear question. please, provide more requirements, with examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can use the `immigrant` gem.
Take a look at https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant

copy/paste from their home page at github:

**Usage**

```
rails generate immigration AddKeys
```

This will create a migration named AddKeys which will have add_foreign_key statements for any missing foreign keys. Immigrant infers missing ones by evaluating the associations in your models (e.g. belongs_to, has_many, etc.). Only missing keys will be added; existing ones will never be altered or removed.

**end of copy/paste**

As it is said, it will create a migration... will not hook into anything else to automatically detect in your new migrations that there's a foreign key and will add it.

Answer (score 0):

schema_plus (https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus) will automatically add foreign keys when migrations are added. I've been using it for years but hoping now with native foreign key support with Rails 4.2, that the automatic hook will also be available at some point. In the meantime, this gem works great.